# How to initiate Three.js PointerLockControls when camera is not at origin?

Tags: three.js, pointerlock

I am trying to use PointerLockControls in my three.js game and I want my player to start from another point but not from origin.

Let's say I want to start playing from 1000,0,0. If I place: `camera.position.set(1000, 0, 0)` in line 193 in 
http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock

then the example shows a weird behavior: When I move the mouse the camera is orbiting around origin with a radius of 1000. I would expect to start first person view from 1000,0,0. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it my self. Controls should be moved, not the camera.

Just add

```
controls.getObject().position.set(1000, 0, 0);
```

in line 204 and it works fine.